# Reduction from Hamiltonian path to Tripartite decision problem

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions, hamiltonian-path

I teach a fairly advanced algorithms class to high schoolers and I accidentally presented them with a bunk reduction from Hamiltonian path to the Tripartite graph decision problem.

My attempt involved creating three vertices in the transformed input $G'$ for every one vertex in the original undirected graph $G$ and connecting them sparsely. For an edge $(u, v)$ in $G$, I was creating $(u_1, v_2)$, $(u_2, v_3)$, and $(u_3, v_1)$ in $G'$. This obviously doesn’t work for several reasons that I did not realize because it worked on two examples and I was tired. Particularly, if a vertex has degree $\geq 3$ in $G$, then this transformation will always cause the tripartite algorithm to answer false regardless of if $G$ has a Hamiltonian path.

Is there a simple-ish reduction that I can show them to correct my mistake, or do I have to go through SAT or something like that?

Comment: Its like asking for a reduction from hampath to 3 color. I don't expect an easy direct reduction.